# Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [mdVirtualRepeat, ngInclude] asking for transclusion

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I've got a problem using `mdVirtualRepeat` directive in my html page. The problem is that I need include a html in the same tag. This is what I should need to do:

```
<table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
       <th ng-repeat="header in headers">
           {{header.title}}
       </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody md-virtual-repeat-container 
          id="vertical-container"
          md-auto-shrink = "true"
          md-virtual-repeat="item in items.list"
          data-ng-include="./details.html'">
   </tbody>
</table>
```

and the `details.html` page contains the columns of my table with 2 tr. Something like:

```
<tr>
   <td>
     {{item..}}
   </td>
   <td>
      {{item..}}
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan="2">
      {{item..}}
   </td>
</tr>
```

The real problem is that `item` need to use it in all detail.html page. So I can't loop for example in the first `<tr>` tag because in the second I can't use it any more. But in this way I can't use the directive because I get this error: `Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [mdVirtualRepeat, ngInclude] asking for transclusion`

Is there a way to solve the problem?

EDIT:
Or is it possible something like this?

```
 <tr md-virtual-repeat="item in items.list">
   <td>
     {{item..}}
   </td>
   <td>
      {{item..}}
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan="2">
      {{item..}} (use item also here out of ng-repeat?)
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: do you want `details.html` to appear after your `items`, or before, or somehow mixed in together?

Comment: what i need is loop all details.html with md-virtual-repeat as i posted. But in that way i have the error.

Comment: Maybe you should create a simple directive, that `details.html` is its template

Comment: can you show me how could i do it please?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a directive. Something like:

```
yourModule.directive('details', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'details.html'
  };
});
```

And then:

```
<tbody md-virtual-repeat-container 
      id="vertical-container"
      md-auto-shrink = "true"
      md-virtual-repeat="item in items.list"
      details>
```

**Edit**:
Here is a [simplified example](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Kr2hTFiyq8yy00rzUBl?p=preview)

Comment: still same error.. and, if i do the md-virtual-repeat in the first <tr> tag is it possible use item also in the second? i try to edit so you can see what i mean

Comment: The two `tr`s are siblings, so yes, I think you need 2 `ng-repeat`s

Comment: and using only one ng-repeat isn't possibile?

Comment: i can't use 2 ng-repeat for each tr :(

Comment: I've created a simple example of my solution. hope it gives you some guidance. http://plnkr.co/edit/2Kr2hTFiyq8yy00rzUBl?p=preview